# Query with LIKE statement for any of the words, not whole

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Name LIKE '%' +
    (SELECT TOP 1 Gift.Name FROM Gift WHERE Id = 65)
     + '%'
```

Subquery returns sth like "toy gun". Some of them even consists of three or more words. Obviously main query looks for Names that include "toy gun".
What I want to do is return all results for "toy" or "gun".

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you able and willing to use Full-Text Indexing?

Comment: Can you use Stored Procedure and/or functions? Also, can you write your own application using other languages such as C#, JAVA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create function that splits out the text of your column.  Here is one possible way to do it:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Once you have that, you can use a JOIN with a LIKE:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Products p
INNER JOIN dbo.fnSplitString
           (
             SELECT TOP 1 Gift.Name FROM Gift WHERE Id = 65
           ) sub ON p.Name LIKE '%' + sub.splitdata + '%'
```

(I'm sure that's not 100% correct syntax.)

Comment: Same as my answer.   You can join directly to dbo.fnSplitString, no need to do "SELECT * FROM".

Comment: Good catch--updated.  I don't see how this is the same as your answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman What I was trying to say is, you won't get the correct result because in the `LIKE` statement, you will eventually end up having `p.Name LIKE %(a bunch of strings from the split table)%`. Essentially, you need to find a way to form a query something like: `p.NAME like %word1' OR p.NAME like %word2' OR p.NAME like %word3'` and so on

Comment: @C.J. Agree--however, the join to the results of a table-value function will allow this.  So this answer should work.

Comment: A split function doesn't work that way, CJ, it returns a table with one column and a row for every word, not one row and a column for every word.  My solution is exactly the same as Phil's, I just didn't write out an example of how the SQL would look.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Full Text indexing enabled then using `FREETEXT` query produce what you want. You can check Full Text if it enabled by running the below query:

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

If the above returns 1, then your good to go. If 0 is returned then search for installation instructions for your SQL Server version. Here is a good guide to setting up the FullText index http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/09/05/sql-server-creating-full-text-catalog-and-index/.

Once set up you can use the below code to perform your required search:

```
Declare @searchString nvarchar (100);

Select top 1 @searchString = Gift.Name FROM Gift WHERE Id=65;

Select * From Products Where FREETEXT (Name, @searchString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @query varchar(8000)
select @query='
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Name LIKE ''%' +
    replace((SELECT TOP 1 Gift.name FROM Gift),' ','%'' or name like ''%')
     + '%'''

    exec (@query)
```

Comment: heh, nice thought, but it wouldn't work.   'Toy Gun' would be become 'Toy%Gun', which still wouldn't return true against 'Toy'.  All you're doing is instead of having to exactly match 'Toy Gun' it can match 'Toy' plus any set of characters plus 'Gun'.  But 'Gun' would still have to be there.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks a lot...It's really tricky way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a split function on Gift.name, to generate a table of single-word names, and link to that table on Product.Name LIKE '%'+SplitFunctionTable.Name+'%'.

If you don't already have a split function in your database, Google can show you some.

Comment: This is not helpful, you cannot have `LIKE % (every word in that table) %'

Comment: Also, there is no "Split" function in SQL, unless you create one yourself. The closest one you can get is `SUBSTRING`

Comment: Sorry CJ, you're wrong.  1)  You absolutely can JOIN ... ON ... LIKE, which would do a LIKE operation on every row in that column of the table.   2)  Did you miss the second part of my answer where I told the OP how to find a split function for SQL?   Sorry if anyone thought I was implying the function was built-in.   You might want to un-do your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This chops a string of two words delimited by one space into single words

```
declare @s nvarchar (30)='toy gun'
select LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX(' ',@s)+1,len(@s)))
select LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, 0,CHARINDEX(' ',@s)+1))
```

Maybe this helps. Looks ugly though from any angle...

Comment: OP did mention that the word can be 2 or more, so how are you going to know how many times you need to write that select statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE Name LIKE '%' +
    (SELECT TOP 1 Gift.Name FROM Gift WHERE Id = 65)
     + '%'
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but if you don't want to create function.

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ' ' + (SELECT TOP 1 Gift.Name FROM Gift WHERE Id = 65) + ' '
  LIKE '%' + ' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       Name,'[','[[]'), '_', '[_]'), '%', '[%]') + ' ' + '%'
```

.

```
Gift.Name         Products.Name
' toy gun ' LIKE '% toy %' true
' toy gun ' LIKE '% gun %' true
' toy gun ' LIKE '% toy gun %' true
' toy gun ' LIKE '% guns %' false
' toy gun ' LIKE '% gu %' false
' toy gun ' LIKE '% to %' false
' toy gun ' LIKE '% toys %' false
' toy gun ' LIKE '% gun toy %' false
```